# How to add -sPAPERSIZE=a4 to makefile?

Tags: parameters, makefile

i have this makefile:

```
FILE=name

all:
    latex $(FILE).tex
    dvips $(FILE).dvi
    ps2pdf $(FILE).ps
```

and i want to add parameter -sPAPERSIZE=a4 for latex, dvips and ps2pdf, how should i do it?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Welcome! Why can't you just add it in? What's the problem? I'm not sure *why* you would want to add that in like that but, if you do, I don't see why you can't. I can see why you might want to add it for `dvips` and `ps2pdf` but does it make any sense to add it for `latex`? And given that, does it make sense to add it for the others either?

Comment: It will normally be better to set the page size *in* the `.tex` file. Otherwise you run the risk of TeX thinking the page dimensions are one thing and the external cropping doing something else. If you are concerned about TeX defaulting to `letterpage` when you want `a4`, you can use `tlmgr` to reconfigure the defaults.

Comment: `latex` doesn't take a command line argument `-sPAPERSIZE=a4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
FILE=   name
SIZE=   -sPAPERSIZE=a4

all:
    latex $(FILE).tex
    dvips $(SIZE) $(FILE).dvi
    ps2pdf $(SIZE) $(FILE).ps
```

However, this Makefile doesn't really use what Make is designed for. You could as well implement this in a shell script (or batch file). `latex` doesn't accept the `-s` flag.

Comment: I need this makefile for school project. And thank you very much, it works well.